# Take certain parts of multipe rosbags and merge these to one rosbag

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to take  different parts from a rosbag (multiple rosbags) and put them all together at the end to one final rosbag?

So for example:
take from 1.bag: 30s - 55s
take from 2.bag: 75s - 90s
take from 3.bag: 40s - 60s

merge these 3 parts to final.bag

all of these bags have the same topic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122761/take-certain-parts-of-multipe-rosbags-and-merge-these-to-one-rosbag/) by [jringel77](https://answers.ros.org/users/11271/jringel77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you will have to write your own tool. It should be quite easy with the rosbag python api. I have small scripts for time filtering and merging and of bag files and they are all quite straight forward.

Edit: Here are the scripts. The time filtering is actually just a hacky invocation of a rosbag filter, but the merge script is gerneral purpose and you can even select only wanted topics with wildcards.

https://gist.github.com/NikolausDemmel/8944211

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on 2014-02-11**:
Thanks!!!!

**Comment by [davelkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23120/davelkan/) on 2015-07-09**:
hey Demmeln could you explain how to properly use rosbag_filter_subsequence.sh? This tool seems to be exactly what I need, but I can't seem to get time filtering to work and ended up with a 2.7 gb bag file spanning multiple days

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2015-07-19**:
It is not a general purpose tool, but just an example of how you might want to use "rosbag filter". You will have to adapt it to your use case.